# Permission Problem with RAID1 device

Tags: permissions, samba, raid, fstab, mdadm

I'm experiencing some trouble with an home server (Ubuntu 20.04.3) that I have put on.

My configuration:
1 Software RAID1 (mdadm) that is mounted via fstab to /media/altocasa/NetDisk1

I have also activated a samba share to share a folder on that disk.
The other folders on the disk are dedicated to various services:
-owncloud
-transmission
-calibre
-kodi

My problem is about...permissions! That's because even if I managed to mount the folder with a "data" group that contains every user that needs to R/W on that disk, and even if permissions are set to drwxrwxrwx, every service I try to use reports that they don't have enough permissions to write on any folder inside the disk.

My **mdadm.conf**

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0777 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR admin@basat.org

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Wed, 02 Nov 2016 00:28:16 +0100
# by mkconf $Id$

ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 spares=1 name=altocasa.alto:0 UUID=abf104eb:c48a9898:e19f5e29:b810dc85
```

My **fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/mmcblk0p2 during installation
UUID=0051b1ea-f028-4e24-852e-60f0e14deba5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/mmcblk0p1 during installation
UUID=3AC6-9820  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
#raid mount point /dev/md0
#UUID=abf104eb:c48a9898:e19f5e29:b810dc85 /media/altocasa/NetDisk1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,silent,permissions,x-gvfs-show umask=000,utf8 0 0
#UUID=1EFCAB415200A4AB  /media/altocasa/NetDisk1 auto nosuid,nodev,users,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000,gid=1001 0 0
#UUID=abf104eb:c48a9898:e19f5e29:b810dc85  /media/altocasa/NetDisk1 auto nosuid,rw,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,users,uid=1000,gid=1001,permissions,utf8 0 0
/dev/md0  /media/altocasa/NetDisk1 auto nosuid,rw,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,users,uid=1000,gid=1001,permissions,utf8 0 0
```

My **Samba Config file**

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
    map to guest = bad user
    workgroup = workgroup
    logging = file
    netbios aliases = altoserver,altocasa
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_SNDBUF=131072 SO_RCVBUF=131072
    netbios name = AltoServer
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    default = NetDisk1
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    os level = 20
    auto services = NetDisk1
    max log size = 1000
    server role = standalone server
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    usershare allow guests = yes
    unix password sync = yes
    pam password change = yes
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).

# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.


# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
#   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

#[printers]
#   comment = All Printers
#   browseable = no
#   path = /var/spool/samba
#   printable = yes
#   guest ok = no
#   read only = yes
#   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
#[print$]
#   comment = Printer Drivers
#   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
#   browseable = yes
#   read only = yes
#   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

 

    
[Share]
    path = /media/altocasa/NetDisk1/Shared
    writeable = yes
    directory mode = 777
    create mode = 777
    public = yes
```

Also if I try to use chmod or chown on the mount point (/media/alto...) the command executes without any effective change.

**ls of the disk:**

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     4096 Aug 15  2018  DRIVERs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data  9401704 Dec  2  2019  DTTarget2.1.0.0072.exe
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     8192 Apr 14  2021  FILMs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data 12218104 Mar 22  2021 'Fusion 360 Client Downloader.exe'
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     4096 Oct  4 16:03  ISO
-rwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     1091 May 12  2019  ObstacleAvoidV1.py
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data        0 Oct 28  2016  Programmi
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     4096 Feb 12  2017 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     4096 Apr  8  2021  Torrent
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data      264 Feb  2 20:03  UNLISTED
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     4096 Mar 23  2021  Vpn
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     4096 Jan 27 15:01  html
drwxrwxrwx 1 altocasa data     4096 Jan 27 15:02  openrsd
```

I'm literally out of options. Does anyone know why the hell an user (www-data) that is inside the data group can't read write on a data owned folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue related to AppArmor. By default, Apache *cannot* write to locations outside of `/var/www` regardless of what permissions the `www-data` account may have. This is to ensure that a website cannot write files to arbitrary locations on your server.

There are generally two options here:

1. Mount the device to a location *inside* `/var/www` (easy)
2. Modify your AppArmor policies for Apache, allowing `rw` access to `/media/altocasa/NetDisk1` (less-easy)

For many of my servers, I go with the first option and mount the storage device to `/var/www/files`. Inside this location will be directories for each website (NextCloud, RoundCube, etc.).

Comment: Thank you! Moving to var/www solved it.